# How to dynamically remove values from Grid in XAML?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Am new to Xamarin.

Right now I have implemented a grid in the XAML, with one row and 5 columns.

The expectation is like, when the element in the 3rd column does not have any values to show(null or empty), it will be removed and the 4th column element comes to 3rd and 5th column element comes to 4th.

How is this achievable?

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Consider using ListView or StackLayout.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `Height` property to hide the row of Grid in the [RowDefinition](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.RowDefinition/).

With one Row hidden :

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    <RowDefinition Height="0" />   <-- this row is hidden-->
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

With all rows shown :

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />   
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

You can also bind the [Height](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.RowDefinition.Height/) to a property of your ViewModel.

```
public GridLength GridRowHeight { get; set; }
```